# Bash: remove all but last 10 log files

Tags: regex, bash, file

I have a custom application that creates log files per order. The log files have random names. I would like to keep only 10 newest files.

So far, I got here:

```
ls -lrth /var/log/myapp/ | awk {'print $9'} | tail -n10
```

This command gives me a list of 10 newest files. Now, I would like to delete everything else but these files. Is there a way to get a list of all files except of these 10 newest files, or how do I delete all but these 10 files?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for i in $(ls -lrth /var/log/myapp/ | awk {'print $9'} | head -n -10) ; do echo $i ; done
```

Check the output and if satisfied replace echo with rm.

Comment: That would remove the first 10.

Answer (score 2):

This find will give you all but last 10 most recent modified files:

```
find . -exec stat --format="%X" + | sort -n | tail -n+10
```

Similar list using `ls`:

```
ls -lt|tail -n+10
```